# Python Flask: Same Response Returned for New Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, repeat

Python newbie here. I have a basic Flask API to price check a car's make and model.

**Expected Behavior:**
The purpose is to send a GET request to the server like this:

http://127.0.0.1:5000//EndPoint1?CarMakeModel=ChevySilverado

And the response should return the price: $25000

If I submit a second request like this:

http://127.0.0.1:5000//EndPoint1?CarMakeModel=FordPinto

The response should return the price: $5000

**Incorrect Observed Behavior:**
When I make a GET request for ChevySilverado (like the URL above), it returns $25000 correctly. But when I send a second URL for FordPinto, it returns $25000 again instead of $5000. **It will always repeat $25000 as the output.**

How can I get this Python code to return $5000 when I submit 'FordPinto' on the second request URL?

Here's the code I've tried:

```
#PriceCheck.py:

from Flask import request
PriceChecker=[]
Price=[]
PriceChecker= request.args.get('CarMakeModel')
if PriceChecker == 'ChevySilverado':
    Price = '$25000'
if PriceChecker == 'FordPinto':
    Price = '$5000'

#Run.py:

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/EndPoint1')
def Response():
    from PriceCheck import PriceChecker
    return str(PriceChecker)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is it a typo or your if statements really don't have colons at the end?

Comment: Both your example URLs are the same. I assume one is supposed to have the `FordPinto` value? Just checking that you didn't actually make the same request twice, which would of course explain why you got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Price` is a module global variable, it is is only set once, when `PriceCheck.py` is first imported.  You should instead wrap the code in `PriceCheck.py` in a function so that it can be called repeatedly:

New `PriceCheck.py`:

```
from Flask import request

def check_price():
    PriceChecker= request.args.get('CarMakeModel')
    if PriceChecker == 'ChevySilverado':
        Price = '$25000'
    if PriceChecker == 'FordPinto':
        Price = '$5000'
    # You also need to handle `PriceChecker` being other values!
    return Price
```

New `Run.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from PriceCheck import check_price

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/EndPoint1')
def Response():
    return check_price()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```